# Update and sort List after an action from a button

Tags: swift, sorting, swiftui, swiftui-list

My application has a List with medications that notify the user first in a specific date that the user set and after pressing a button it will repeat daily, weekly,... The List is sorted to have the next medication on top, but when I press the button the date changes but the order of the medications don´t, is there a way to reload the list inside my button action?
Here´s my View code:

```
struct ContentView: View {


@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Medication.date, ascending: true)])

private var medications: FetchedResults<Medication>
  

var body: some View {
    TabView {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(medications, id: \.self) { (medication: Medication) in
                    HStack {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle").font(.system(size: 35, weight: .regular)).onTapGesture {
                                updateQuantity(medication) 
                            }
                                Text("Next Date: \(medication.nextDate ?? Date() ,formatter: itemFormatter)")
                                    .font(.body)
                                    .fontWeight(.light)


private func updateQuantity(_ medication: FetchedResults<Medication>.Element) {
    withAnimation {
            medication.nextDate = Date(timeInterval: medication.repeatSeconds, since: medication.nextDate ?? Date())
         
    }
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. There is a lot going on in your code that is not necessary. Please simplify it. Also, You haven't shown how to plan to change the sorting of your list. A couple of suggestions though. Since you are diving into iOS 15 you should avoid deprecated methods such as `navigationBarItems` and use `toolbar` also. Review the relevant WWDC videos for the most current information right now. For this look at "Bring Core Data concurrency to Swift and SwiftUI"

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks for the tip, will look into that and I tried to clean my code to only show where I got the problem